I need to cut/copy/paste many files with longer than MAX_PATH filenames using clipboard, unicode aware. Language is VB6, and environment is Win10 x64
I did some code to copy/paste files into clipboard and is working well, filenames exceeding MAX_PATH.
I am using prepend ("\?") probably does not matter for the clipboard anyway.
Declares:
Option Explicit
'md_ClipboardCopyPasteFiles002


Private Declare Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32" (ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare Sub MoveMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef Destination As Any, ByRef Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)

Private Declare Function DragQueryFile Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "DragQueryFileA" (ByVal hDrop As Long, ByVal UINT As Long, ByVal lpStr As String, ByVal ch As Long) As Long

'
Private Const GMEM_MOVEABLE = &H2
Private Const GMEM_ZEROINIT = &H40
Private Const GHND = (GMEM_MOVEABLE Or GMEM_ZEROINIT)

'
Private Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare Function SetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long, ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function RegisterClipboardFormat Lib "user32" Alias "RegisterClipboardFormatA" (ByVal lpString As String) As Long

'
Private Const CF_HDROP = 15


Private Const CFSTR_PREFERREDDROPEFFECT As String = "Preferred DropEffect"

Private Type POINTAPI
   x As Long
   y As Long
End Type

Private Type DROPFILES
   pFiles As Long
   pt As POINTAPI
   fNC As Long
   fWide As Long
End Type

'______Public__________________
Public Enum FileDropEffectConstants
  fdDropEffectNone = 0
  fdDropEffectCopy = 1
  fdDropEffectmove = 2
  fdDropEffectLink = 4
End Enum

I am using this code to put files to Clipboard:

Public Function ClipboardSetFiles(Files() As String, Optional ByVal lEffect As Long) As Boolean
Dim i As Long
   
If OpenClipboard(0&) Then
      
        Call EmptyClipboard
      
        'Concatenate file paths with null terminators
        Dim data As String
        For i = LBound(Files) To UBound(Files)
                data = data & Files(i) & vbNullChar
        Next i
        data = data & vbNullChar
      
        'allocate mem for DropFiles struct
        Dim dF As DROPFILES
        Dim hMem1 As Long
        Dim pMem1 As Long
        hMem1 = GlobalAlloc(GHND, Len(dF) + Len(data))
        If hMem1 Then
                pMem1 = GlobalLock(hMem1)
                dF.pFiles = Len(dF)
                Call MoveMemory(ByVal pMem1, dF, Len(dF))
                Call MoveMemory(ByVal (pMem1 + Len(dF)), ByVal data, Len(data))
                Call GlobalUnlock(hMem1)
                If SetClipboardData(CF_HDROP, hMem1) Then
                   ClipboardSetFiles = True
                End If
        End If
      
        'alloc memory for the Effect
        Dim hMem2 As Long
        Dim pMem2 As Long
        Dim lFormat As Long
        Dim lReturn As Long

        hMem2 = GlobalAlloc(GHND, Len(lEffect))
        If hMem2 Then
                pMem2 = GlobalLock(hMem2)
                Call MoveMemory(ByVal pMem2, lEffect, Len(lEffect))
                Call GlobalUnlock(hMem2)
                lFormat = RegisterClipboardFormat(CFSTR_PREFERREDDROPEFFECT)
                lReturn = SetClipboardData(lFormat, hMem2)
        End If
      
        Call CloseClipboard
   
End If
End Function


I am using this code to get files:
Public Function ClipboardGetFiles(Files() As String, Optional ByRef DropEffect As FileDropEffectConstants) As Long
Dim hDrop As Long
Dim nFiles As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim fileName As String
'Const MAX_PATH As Long = 260 - NO LONGER USED
Dim lFormat As Long
Dim hMem   As Long
Dim lEffect As Long
   
'interrogate clipboard
If IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_HDROP) Then
        If OpenClipboard(0&) Then
                hDrop = GetClipboardData(CF_HDROP)
                If (hDrop) Then
                        nFiles = DragQueryFile(hDrop, -1&, "", 0)
                        'Debug.Print nFiles
                        ReDim Files(0 To nFiles - 1) As String
                        fileName = Space$(4096) - HERE I INSERTED A LARGER THAN MAX_PATH VALUE
                        For k = 0 To nFiles - 1
                                Call DragQueryFile(hDrop, k, fileName, Len(fileName))
                                Files(k) = TrimNull(fileName)
                                'Debug.Print Files(k)
                                'Debug.Print Len(Files(k))
                        Next k
                        lFormat = RegisterClipboardFormat(CFSTR_PREFERREDDROPEFFECT)
                        hMem = GetClipboardData(lFormat)
                        If (hMem) Then
                                MoveMemory lEffect, ByVal hMem, 4
                                DropEffect = lEffect
                        End If
                End If
                Call CloseClipboard
        End If
        ClipboardGetFiles = nFiles
End If
End Function


I am not sure if this code (specifically the 4096 thing...) does not have troubles getting the filenames, i.e.getting out of application memory space? or anything else...?
Is there now, year 2024, another function to put and get the files from clipboard, one who can use strings to be allocated dynamically when taking data, not fixed-length strings, also files to be recognizable by the system (Windows Explorer) to be able cu cut/copy/paste files independent of my application only? seems like windows Explorer still cannot paste filenames longer than MAX_PATH

My functions worked as expected, at least a few tries; but seems that Windows Explorer does not recognize the longer than MAX_PATH filenames whet trying to get them from clipboard, even with "\?"  ( \ \ ? \ )included in filenames.

"Is there now, year 2024, another function to put and get the files from clipboard..." Being that VB6 was released in 1998, the answer would be 'no' for VB6.
